# Is it true that UTP cables are more resistant to noise than the cables used for serial communication?

Tags: networking, serial-port, noise

I have some questions about the noise handling capabilities of the cables.

Often RS232 or RS422 cables are used for serial communication, while UTP cables communicate using reliable protocols such as TCP communication, which makes UTP cables more resistant to noise.

Is it true that UTP cables are more resistant to noise than RS232 or RS422 cables?

Comment: The protocol used over the wire is totally irrelevant to the noise rejection characteristics of the cable itself.  Plenty of people use(d) TCP over RS-232, and other physical interfaces.

Comment: @Brad Oh, I know about that, but I usually use it that way, so I was wondering if the noise handling capability of the cable itself was actually proportional.

Comment: *"UTP cables communicate using reliable protocols such as TCP communication"* -- That's a bogus association.  TCP is a layer above Internet Protocol (i.e. IP) which is considered an unreliable protocol. As for RS232 installations, I've seen shielded cable used in "noisy" environments.